# On the weak derivative of $|u|^{(p-2)/2}u$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde

Let $u$ be a function such that $|u|^{(p-2)/2}u$ is in $H^1_0(G)$, $G$ is open and $p>2$.

How can I show that
$$
D(|u|^{(p-2)/2}u)=p/2|u|^{(p-2)/2}D(u) \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
or how can I show that, if $G$ is bounded then
$$
u\in W^{1,p}_0(G) \label{2}\tag{2}\;?
$$
Note that \eqref{2} implies \eqref{1}.

\eqref{1} is stated in the proof of Lemma 1 in a work of Raviart "Sur la résolution et l'approximation de certaines équations paraboliques non linéaires dégénérées", Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis, 25, 64-80 (1967), [MR215544](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=215544), [Zbl 0153.42202](https://zbmath.org/0153.42202).

Remark: The provided answer below showed that \eqref{2} can't hold given the above assumptions. I really appreciate the answer. \eqref{1} is still open.

Comment: What difficulty are you having? Just applying the product rule (with being careful with conditions) is not enough?

Comment: Where do you know that $u$ has a weak derivative or $|u|^{(p-2)/2}$?

Comment: For example, you can mollify $u$ and get the wanted identity, then show the identity is preserved when mollification sent to identity? Of course we have to show some estimates along the way?

Comment: I cant quite follow, how does that imply that for $u$ being some function that its weak derivative exists?

Comment: @JingeonAn-Lacroix do you have an idea how to show for a smooth function approaching $u$, that its weak derivatives also converge in $L^1_{loc}$ at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a partial answer : (2) seems strange. In dimension $1$, if $u$ does not change sign, your setting includes the one of $u^\alpha \in H^1(0,1)$ (boundary values are irrelevant here) for some $\alpha>1$ and you're asking if it's enough to get $u' \in L^{2\alpha}(0,1)$.

For $\alpha>1$ and $u(x)=x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ then $u^\alpha$ certainly belongs to $H^1(0,1)$ but the singularity of $u'(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{1}{x^{1-\frac{1}{\alpha}}}$ is not in $L^{2\alpha}(0,1)$, at least for $\alpha$ large enough.

EDIT:

I think (1) implies, one way or another, that $D(u)$ is locally integrable, at least I don't understand this equality if it's not the case ; the counterexample below shows that this is false in general so for (1) to be satisfied, I believe something's missing.

The function $u:x \mapsto x\cos(1/x)$ is bounded on $L^\infty(0,1)$ but is not in $W^{1,1}(0,1)$. Indeed, $$u'(x)=\cos(1/x)+\frac{\sin(1/x)}{x},$$

where the first part of the sum is bounded and the second not integrable on $(0,1)$ because related to the improper integral of $z\mapsto\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ on $(1,+\infty)$. However, computing the derivative of $u^3=|u|^2u$ we get
$$
3u(x)^2u'(x) = 3 x^2\cos(1/x)^3 + 3x\cos(1/x)^2\sin(1/x),
$$
which is bounded on $(0,1)$. We have therefore $|u|^2 u\in H^1(0,1)$ but $u\notin W^{1,1}(0,1)$.

Now, as noticed by the Perelman in the comments, this is not yet a counterxample because $u$ is not $W^{1,1}(0,1)$ but yet is $W^{1,1}_{\text{loc}}(0,1)$. However, replacing $u$ by its reflection  $v\in L^\infty(-1,1)$ which is even and equals $u$ on $(0,1)$, I think $v'$ is not $W^{1,1}_{\text{loc}}(-1,1)$.

Comment: Nice counter example. It seems that (2) can not hold with these assumptions, thank you. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Perelman: on MathOverflow it is generally considered bad practice to edit the question to invalidate an answer after others have taken the time to help you. I would suggest reverting the question to the original form, and then asking a ***new*** question that is of  the current form.

Comment: @WillieWong The old version of the question is essentially similar to the current one. The old one was stated in a way that didn't make sense. The main question didn't change at all. Furthermore, the answer from AymanMoussa, which was provided here, didn't answer the actual question but helped to realize that the post must be edited. I gave him credit for that. If others now worked out a correct answer to the old version, it would imply that it is also an answer to the new version. Therefore, I will not make a new post.

Comment: @WillieWong Nevertheless, thank you for raising awareness.

Comment: @Perelman : In addition to [Willie Wong
's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/468035/on-the-weak-derivative-of-up-2-2u#comment1215311_468047): According to [these MathOverflow guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer), users should "avoid trying to answer questions which [...] request answers to multiple questions". You had two questions, without saying which one you considered "[t]he main question". Ayman Moussa provided what you called "[n]ice counter example" to your second question.

Comment: Previous comment continued: So, the best way to proceed here is to accept Ayman Moussa's answer, and then perhaps post the remaining question separately. That would also be in accordance with the spirit, if not the letter, of [these other guidlenes](https://mathoverflow.net/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'm sure Ayman Moussa was very aware that this wasn't an answer to my question, as he refers to it as a partial answer.
Actually, it isn't an answer at all; it just clarified that the question was ill-posed and needed correction. 
I suggest that you don't follow guidelines blindly but rather use your common sense. 
Nevertheless I will accept his answer because he invested time to provide help and his post helped me still to takle the actual problem.

Comment: @Perelman : I am glad to see that you did the right thing and accepted the answer. However, I don't see any evidence that "Ayman Moussa was very aware that this wasn't an answer to [your] question", "an answer at all". To the contrary, he wrote "Only a partial answer : (2) seems strange". Indeed, he provided an answer to your question (2). I agree with you that we should always try to use common sense. Also, we should carefully recheck our questions before posting them, to avoid posting "ill-posed [questions that] needed correction" and thus avoid wasting other people's time.

Comment: @Perelman : Your post again contains two questions, which is against the sense of the [previously mentioned guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer). Also, keeping two questions still undermines, unfairly, Ayman Moussa's answer.

Comment: Wow. That escalated quickly. Thanks Iosif and Willie for your messages that I understood as a careful concern for MO's community. For Perelman, I reassure you : I did not waste that much of a time ... I'll try to see if I get a complete answer :D

Comment: @AymanMoussa, again a beautiful answer, thank you. It also provided me with valuable insights and allowed me to review Lebesgue theory. However, it is not necessary for $u$ or its derivative to be integrable over the entire domain $(0,1)$. It's only a matter of whether it's appropriate to write $D(u)$, for which $u$ and $D(u)$ need only be locally integrable. If you integrate $\sin(1/x)/x$ over $[a,b]\subseteq (0,1)$, it is Riemann integrable and hence Lebesgue integrable over $[a,b]$. So, (1) is not wrong at all.

Comment: @Perelman I thought that something was wrong and erased the edit, I'll try to rectify it and post it tonight !

Comment: @AymanMoussa Thank you very much for your efforts. But keep in mind that this article https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00281422 has been around for a while now and in google scholar alone, it was cited by 44 others. I would be surprised if the statement is completely wrong. Also Raviart is a distinguished mathematician.

Comment: The number of citation of the paper and the reputation of Pierre-Arnaud are a bit off topic, don't you think ? :) We're speaking of a tiny technical lemma, which apparently misses an assumption, this does not mean that the remaining (interesting) part of the article is wrong ...

Comment: @AymanMoussa absolutely, but I hope that its true because it would have significant impact on other results, Im interested in, that rely on that lemma. But offcourse anything could be, it could even be wrong, so I appreciate any sort of clarification.